# Hex String to Character in PURE Swift

Tags: swift, unicode, utf-8, hex, character

I need a way to convert a string that contains a literal string representing a hexadecimal value into a Character corresponding to that particular hexadecimal value.

Ideally, something along these lines:

```
let hexString: String = "2C"
let char: Character = fromHexString(hexString)
println(char)   // prints -> ","
```

I've tried to use the syntax: "\u{n}" where n is a Int or String and neither worked.

This could be used to loop over an array of hexStrings like so:

```
var hexArray = ["2F", "24", "40", "2A"]
var charArray = [Character]()
charArray = map(hexArray) { charArray.append(Character($0)) }
charArray.description // prints -> "[/, $, @, *]"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple of things about your code:

```
var charArray = [Character]()
charArray = map(hexArray) { charArray.append(Character($0)) }
```

You don't need to create an array and then assign the result of the map, you can just assign the result and avoid creating an unnecessary array.

```
charArray = map(hexArray) { charArray.append(Character($0)) }
```

Here you can use `hexArray.map` instead of `map(hexArray)`, also when you use a map function what you are conceptually doing is mapping the elements of the receiver array to a new set of values and the result of the mapping is the new "mapped" array, which means that you don't need to do `charArray.append` inside the map closure.

Anyway, here is a working example:

```
let hexArray = ["2F", "24", "40", "2A"]
var charArray = hexArray.map { char -> Character in
    let code = Int(strtoul(char, nil, 16))
    return Character(UnicodeScalar(code))
}
println(charArray) // -> [/, $, @, *]
```

**EDIT: This is another implementation that doesn't need Foundation:**

```
func hexToScalar(char: String) -> UnicodeScalar {
    var total = 0
    for scalar in char.uppercaseString.unicodeScalars {
        if !(scalar >= "A" && scalar <= "F" || scalar >= "0" && scalar <= "9") {
            assertionFailure("Input is wrong")
        }

        if scalar >= "A" {
            total = 16 * total + 10 + scalar.value - 65 /* 'A' */
        } else {
            total = 16 * total + scalar.value - 48 /* '0' */
        }
    }
    return UnicodeScalar(total)
}

let hexArray = ["2F", "24", "40", "2A"]
var charArray = hexArray.map { Character(hexToScalar($0)) }
println(charArray)
```

**EDIT2 Yet another option:**

```
func hexToScalar(char: String) -> UnicodeScalar {
    let map = [ "0": 0, "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9,
        "A": 10, "B": 11, "C": 12, "D": 13, "E": 14, "F": 15 ]

    let total = reduce(char.uppercaseString.unicodeScalars, 0, { $0 * 16 + (map[String($1)] ?? 0xff) })
    if total > 0xFF {
        assertionFailure("Input char was wrong")
    }
    return UnicodeScalar(total)
}
```

**Final edit: explanation**

Given that the ascii table has all the number together (012345679), we can convert 'N' (base 10) to an integer knowing the ascii value of 0.

Because:

```
'0': 48
'1': 49
...
'9': 57
```

Then if for example you need to convert '9' to 9 you could do

```
asciiValue('9') - asciiValue('0') => 57 - 48 = 9
```

And you can do the same from 'A' to 'F':

```
'A': 65
'B': 66
...
'F': 70
```

Now we can do the same as before but, for example for 'F' we'd do:

```
asciiValue('F') - asciiValue('A') => 70 - 65 = 5
```

Note that we need to add 10 to this number to get the decimal. Then (going back to the code): If the scalar is between A-Z we need to do:

```
10 + asciiValue(<letter>) - asciiValue('A')
```

which is the same as: `10 + scalar.value - 65`

And if it's between 0-9:

```
asciiValue(<letter>) - asciiValue('0')
```

which is the same as: `scalar.value - 48`

### For example: '2F'

'2' is 2 and 'F' is 15 (by the previous example), right?. Since hex is base 16 we'd need to do:

`((16 ^ 1) * 2) + ((16 ^ 0) * 15) = 47`

Comment: Yes, I see your point there with the map and the Array assignment. As for the use of strtoul( ) that is defined in Darwin's C libraries as apart of importing the Foundation framework. I cannot use this function in this context. No functions in the Foundation framework can be used. Otherwise, the code works. However it isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, one question: Is your hexArray always gonna be ascii-encoded? (as in: no char over 255)?

Comment: Yes they will / should always be ASCII characters

Comment: Just added an hexToScalar method.

Comment: I like the first edit... I'm curious how you came up with the formula for total in each instance... are those the decimal values of the characters?

Comment: Added some explanation let me know if it's not clear.

Answer (score 10):

Here you go:

```
var string = String(UnicodeScalar(Int("2C", radix: 16)!))
```

BTW, you can include hex values in the literal strings like this:

```
var string = "\u{2c}"
```

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 5, you will have to convert your string variable into an integer (using [`init(_:radix:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2924481-init) initializer), create Unicode scalar from this integer (using [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/2906240-init)) then create a character from this Unicode scalar ([`using init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/2906502-init)).

The Swift 5 Playground sample code below shows how to proceed:

```
let validHexString: String = "2C"
let validUnicodeScalarValue = Int(validHexString, radix: 16)!
let validUnicodeScalar = Unicode.Scalar(validUnicodeScalarValue)!
let character = Character(validUnicodeScalar)
print(character) // prints: ","
```

---

If you want to perform this operation for the elements inside an array, you can use the sample code below:

```
let hexArray = ["2F", "24", "40", "2A"]
let characterArray = hexArray.map({ (hexString) -> Character in
    let unicodeScalarValue = Int(hexString, radix: 16)!
    let validUnicodeScalar = Unicode.Scalar(unicodeScalarValue)!
    return Character(validUnicodeScalar)
})
print(characterArray) // prints: ["/", "$", "@", "*"]
```

Alternative with no force unwraps:

```
let hexArray = ["2F", "24", "40", "2A"]
let characterArray = hexArray.compactMap({ (hexString) -> Character? in
    guard let unicodeScalarValue = Int(hexString, radix: 16),
        let unicodeScalar = Unicode.Scalar(unicodeScalarValue) else {
            return nil
    }
    return Character(unicodeScalar)
})
print(characterArray) // prints: ["/", "$", "@", "*"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way based on ICU transforms:

```
extension String {
  func transformingFromHex() -> String? {
    return "&#x\(self);".applyingTransform(.toXMLHex, reverse: true)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
"2C".transformingFromHex()
```

Results in: `,`