# How to express Strings in Swift using Unicode hexadecimal values (UTF-16)

Tags: ios, string, swift, unicode, character

I want to write a Unicode string using hexadecimal values in Swift. I have read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) for String and Character so I know that I can use special Unicode characters directly in strings like the following:

```
var variableString = "Cat‼" // "Cat" + Double Exclamation + cat emoji
```

But I would like to do it using the Unicode code points. The docs (and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983286/characters-and-strings-in-swift)) show it for characters, but are not very clear about how to do it for strings.

(Note: Although the answer seems obvious to me now, it wasn't obvious at all just a short time ago. I am answering my own question below as a means of learning how to do this and also to help myself understand Unicode terminology and how Swift Characters and Strings work.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Character

The Swift syntax for forming a hexadecimal [code point](http://unicode.org/glossary/#code_point) is

```
\u{n}
```

where *n* is a hexadecimal number up to 8 digits long. The valid range for a Unicode [scalar](http://unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value) is U+0 to U+D7FF and U+E000 to U+10FFFF inclusive. (The U+D800 to U+DFFF range is for [surrogate pairs](http://unicode.org/glossary/#surrogate_pair), which are not scalars themselves, but are used in [UTF-16](http://unicode.org/glossary/#UTF_16) for encoding the higher value scalars.)

**Examples:**

```
// The following forms are equivalent. They all produce "C". 
let char1: Character = "\u{43}"
let char2: Character = "\u{0043}"
let char3: Character = "\u{00000043}"

// Higher value Unicode scalars are done similarly
let char4: Character = "\u{203C}" // ‼ (DOUBLE EXCLAMATION MARK character)
let char5: Character = "\u{1F431}" //  (cat emoji)

// Characters can be made up of multiple scalars
let char7: Character = "\u{65}\u{301}" // é = "e" + accent mark
let char8: Character = "\u{65}\u{301}\u{20DD}" // é⃝ = "e" + accent mark + circle
```

**Notes:**

- Leading zeros can be added or omitted
- Characters are known as [*extended grapheme clusters*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID293). Even when they are composed of multiple scalars, they are still considered a single character. What is key is that they appear to be a single character (grapheme) to the user.
- TODO: [How to convert surrogate pair to Unicode scalar in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282675/how-to-convert-surrogate-pair-to-unicode-scalar-in-swift)

### String

Strings are composed of characters. See the following examples for some ways to form them using hexadecimal code points.

**Examples:**

```
var string1 = "\u{0043}\u{0061}\u{0074}\u{203C}\u{1F431}" // Cat‼

// pass an array of characters to a String initializer
let catCharacters: [Character] = ["\u{0043}", "\u{0061}", "\u{0074}", "\u{203C}", "\u{1F431}"] // ["C", "a", "t", "‼", ""]
let string2 = String(catCharacters) // Cat‼
```

### Converting Hex Values at Runtime

At runtime you can convert hexadecimal or `Int` values into a `Character` or `String` by first converting it to a `UnicodeScalar`.

**Examples:**

```
// hex values
let value0: UInt8  = 0x43     // 67
let value1: UInt16 = 0x203C   // 8252
let value2: UInt32 = 0x1F431  // 128049

// convert hex to UnicodeScalar
let scalar0 = UnicodeScalar(value0)
// make sure that UInt16 and UInt32 form valid Unicode values
guard
    let scalar1 = UnicodeScalar(value1),
    let scalar2 = UnicodeScalar(value2) else {
    return
}

// convert to Character
let character0 = Character(scalar0) // C
let character1 = Character(scalar1) // ‼
let character2 = Character(scalar2) // 

// convert to String
let string0 = String(scalar0) // C
let string1 = String(scalar1) // ‼
let string2 = String(scalar2) // 

// convert hex array to String
let myHexArray = [0x43, 0x61, 0x74, 0x203C, 0x1F431] // an Int array
var myString = ""
for hexValue in myHexArray {
    if let scalar = UnicodeScalar(hexValue) {
        myString.append(Character(scalar))
    }
}
print(myString) // Cat‼
```

### Further reading

- [Strings and Characters docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)
- [Glossary of Unicode Terms](http://unicode.org/glossary/)
- [Strings in Swift](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/)
- [Working with Unicode code points in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272561/working-with-unicode-code-points-in-swift)

Comment: @Suragch I have a unicode character `\u{0D85}`. How do I get the Int value from it?

Comment: @Isuru, I have re-asked and answered your question here: [How to convert Unicode Character to Int in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779114/how-to-convert-unicode-character-to-int-in-swift)

Comment: @Suragch Thanks so much for the detailed answer. I actually found how to do it in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24102584/1077789). But still, good to have a thorough explanation.

Comment: @Isuru, Just realize that in the answer you linked to, in the off chance that a `Character` is composed of more than one scalar, only the first scalar value will be returned. Any others will be ignored. (example: `let myChar: Character = "\u{65}\u{301}" // é`)

Comment: how to combine hexadecimal number up to 8 digits long with \u{xxxx}? Hex number is an dynamic

Comment: I am getting hexa decimal number from server like "ef29", I want to append that value into string like "\u{ef29}".. I am not able to do that...

Comment: @karthikeyan, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401010/hex-string-to-character-in-pure-swift)

Comment: Shouldn't this `let value = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)` l do the job?

Comment: You cannot get UnicodeScalars from let value1: UInt16 = 0x203C   // 22823
let value2: UInt32 = 0x1F431. Xcode is showing error

Comment: Also, return in guard is only allowed in function so the code above is not valid

Comment: in what universe 43 hexadecimal is 97?

Comment: @Sebastian, Apparently whatever universe my brain was in when I wrote that. Thanks for the comment. Conversions are fixed for this universe now.

Answer (score 3):

from your Hex "0x1F52D" to actual Emoji

```
let c = 0x1F602
```

next step would possibly getting an Uint32 from your Hex

```
let intEmoji = UnicodeScalar(c!).value
```

from this you can do something like

```
titleLabel.text = String(UnicodeScalar(intEmoji)!)
```

here you have a ""

it work with range of hexadecimal too

```
let emojiRanges = [
            0x1F600...0x1F636,
            0x1F645...0x1F64F,
            0x1F910...0x1F91F,
            0x1F30D...0x1F52D
        ]

        for range in emojiRanges {
            for i in range {
                let c = UnicodeScalar(i)!.value
                data.append(c)
            }
        }
```

to get multiple UInt32 from your Hex range for exemple

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise, be sure you tailor your answer to *this* question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Made this Medium Article that explain how it works https://medium.com/@kamiFR/how-to-show-emojis-with-strings-in-swift-using-unicode-hexadecimal-values-5093448cd1a9

Comment: often same response apply to many questions and I support when author does this