# How to convert an Int to a Character in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, int, character, var

I've struggled and failed for over ten minutes here and I give in. I need to convert an Int to a Character in Swift and cannot solve it.

**Question**

How do you convert (*cast*) an `Int` (*integer*) to a `Character` (*char*) in Swift?

**Illustrative Problem/Task Challenge**

Generate a for loop which prints the letters 'A' through 'Z', e.g. something like this:

```
    for(var i:Int=0;i<26;i++) {      //Important to note - I know 
        print(Character('A' + i));   //this is horrendous syntax...
    }                                //just trying to illustrate! :)
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can't convert an integer directly to a `Character` instance, but you can go from integer to `UnicodeScalar` to `Character` and back again:

```
let startingValue = Int(("A" as UnicodeScalar).value) // 65
for i in 0 ..< 26 {
    print(Character(UnicodeScalar(i + startingValue)))
}
```

Comment: That UnicodeScalar initializer is optional though, and that Character initializer doesn't take an optional. You have to do something more like
`Character(UnicodeScalar(i + startingValue)!)`

Answer (score 12):

## How to convert an Int to a Character in Swift

*For the sake of future visitors, I am providing a basic answer to the question title rather than the details of the question itself.*

It is a two step process. Convert the `Int` to a `UnicodeScalar` and then convert the `UnicodeScalar` to a `Character`.

```
let myInteger: Int = 97

// convert Int to a valid UnicodeScalar
guard let myUnicodeScalar = UnicodeScalar(myInteger) else {
    return
}

// convert UnicodeScalar to Character
let myCharacter = Character(myUnicodeScalar)

// results
print(myCharacter) // a
```

[*(source)*](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-int-character-swift)

Or alternatively...

```
if let myUnicodeScalar = UnicodeScalar(97) 
    let myCharacter = Character(myUnicodeScalar)
}
```

## See also

- [How to express Strings in Swift using Unicode hexadecimal values (UTF-16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284538/how-to-express-strings-in-swift-using-unicode-hexadecimal-values-utf-16)
- [Working with Unicode code points in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31483262/3681880)

Answer (score 11):

try this

```
for i in 0...25
{
    let string = String(format: "%c", i+65) as String
    NSLog("%@", string)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

So far I've come up with this:

```
for i in 0 ..< 26 {
    print(Character(UnicodeScalar(Int(UnicodeScalar("A").value) + i)))
}
```

If you're just trying to generate "A" to "Z", you can avoid the math and just do:

```
for c in UnicodeScalar("A").value...UnicodeScalar("Z").value {
    print(String(UnicodeScalar(c)))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For helpful context, taking vacawama's and Nate Cook's UnicodeScalar to use -

```
 let startingValue = Int(UnicodeScalar("A").value)
 for i in 0..<26 {
    let itemStr = String(UnicodeScalar(i + startingValue))

    items.append("Item " + itemStr)
}
```

Comment: Ok fine... You are right and I hate that. Done! Here is the C-style if anyone wants it -

Comment: for(var i:Int=0; i<26; i++) {

        var itemStr:String = String(UnicodeScalar(i + startingValue));

        items.append(String(format: "Item '%@'", itemStr));
    }

Comment: good catch. I replaced the original "items.append(String(format: "Item '%@'", itemStr))" with your proposal of "items.append("Item " + itemStr)

Answer (score 3):

Simply convert the integer into String, then convert string into Character

```
let number = 5
let numChar = Character(String(number))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension for Int to provide a correspondingLetter function :

```
extension Int {
    func correspondingLetter(inUppercase uppercase: Bool = false) -> String? {
        let firstLetter = uppercase ? "A" : "a"
        let startingValue = Int(UnicodeScalar(firstLetter)!.value)
        if let scalar = UnicodeScalar(self + startingValue) {
            return String(scalar)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Note that if the int is larger then 26 you'll get special characters.

Answer (score 1):

New and updated

```
for charac in Unicode.Scalar("A").value...Unicode.Scalar("Z").value {
    print(Unicode.Scalar(charac)!, terminator:" ")}
```

prints:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

thx for the help from @vacawama, I like this version, for Swift(5) especially because of:

```
for charac in Unicode.Scalar("a").value...Unicode.Scalar("z").value {
    print(Unicode.Scalar(charac)!, terminator:" ")}
```

prints:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

and not having to look up, even tho we should know our unicode? haha etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
//Current swift version is 5.7

//Prints character of unicode scaler 65
let num = 65
if let character = UnicodeScalar(num) {
    print(character) // prints A
}

//Similarly looping over 'a...z' 
let numRange = 97...122
for num in numRange {
    print("\(num) = \(UnicodeScalar(num)!)")
}
```