# How to compose multi-character emoji from raw hex

Tags: ios, unicode, swift2, emoji

I'm getting JSON like this from the server:

```
{
    "unicode":"1f468-1f468-1f467-1f467"
}
```

and I'm supposed to translate it into its composite character for display and/or copying to the pasteboard: ‍‍‍

The solution so far comes from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401010/hex-string-to-character-in-pure-swift?rq=1):

```
let u = json["unicode"] as? String
let dashless = u.characters.split{$0 == "-"}.map(String.init)
let charArray = dashless.map { char -> Character in
    let code = Int(strtoul(char, nil, 16))
    return Character(UnicodeScalar(code))
}
let unicode = String(charArray)
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = unicode
```

This works *great* for single-character emoji definitions.

E.g., I can run the code above with this JSON…

```
{
    "unicode":"1f4a9"
}
```

…and paste the expected result: . But when I do with the `mmgg` family emoji listed earlier, I get the following in iOS, minus the spaces: ‍ ‍ ‍ . They just don't seem to want to combine when pasted into a text field.

Is this an iOS bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this in your playground, to see the difference ...

```
"".unicodeScalars.forEach { (c) in
    print(c.escape(asASCII: true),terminator: "")
}

print("")

"‍‍‍".unicodeScalars.forEach { (c) in
    print(c.escape(asASCII: true), terminator: "")
}

/*
 \u{0001F468}\u{0001F468}\u{0001F467}\u{0001F467}
 \u{0001F468}\u{200D}\u{0001F468}\u{200D}\u{0001F467}\u{200D}\u{0001F467}
 */
```

your original, slightly modified code

```
import Darwin // stroul

let u = "1f468-1f468-1f467-1f467"
let dashless = u.characters.split{$0 == "-"}.map(String.init)
let emoji = dashless.map { char -> String in
    let code = Int(strtoul(char, nil, 16))
    return String(UnicodeScalar(code))
    }.joinWithSeparator("\u{200D}")

print(emoji) // ‍‍‍
```

pure Swift code, no Foundation, without strtoul

```
let u = "1f468-1f468-1f467-1f467"
let emoji = u.characters.split("-")
    .map {String(UnicodeScalar(Int(String($0),radix: 16) ?? 0))}
    .joinWithSeparator("\u{200D}")

print(emoji) // ‍‍‍
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant! Didn't know about the [zero-width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner).

Comment: Hate to bother you again, but it seems that this solution doesn't work for emoji with tone modifiers. E.g., this JSON yields hands and a color square rather than just tone-3 hands: `let u = "1f64c-1f3fd"`…

Comment: Was hoping not to complicate my code so much, but the blank separator fixes the issue with tones. Thanks!