# Stubborn emoji won't combine: ‍❤‍‍

Tags: ios, unicode, swift2, emoji

Even after @user3441734 [solved most of my problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216598/how-to-compose-multi-character-emoji-from-raw-hex) , there are a few emoji that I can't seem to render properly when converting from a [String:String] to String.

Here's some Playground-ready code to illustrate the problem:

```
var u = ""
u = "1f468-1f468-1f467-1f467" // ‍‍‍
//u = "1f918-1f3ff" // 
//u = "1f468-2764-1f48b-1f468" // ‍❤‍‍ (broken)
//u = "1f3c7-1f3fb" // ‍ (broken)

let unicodeArray = u.characters.split("-")
    .map(String.init)
    .map {String(UnicodeScalar(Int($0,radix: 16) ?? 0))}

if let last = unicodeArray.last {
    let separator: String
    switch (unicodeArray.first, last) {
        // Failed attempt to get tone applied to jockey
    case let (horse_racing, _) where horse_racing == "\u{1f3c7}":
        separator = "\u{200d}"
    case let (_, tone) where "\u{1f3fb}"..."\u{1f3ff}" ~= tone:
        separator = ""
    case let (_, regionalIndicatorSymbol) where "\u{1f1e6}"..."\u{1f1ff}" ~= regionalIndicatorSymbol:
        separator = ""
    default:
        separator = "\u{200d}"
    }
    print(unicodeArray.joinWithSeparator(separator))
}
```

Uncomment each assignment to `u` in turn to see the problem in action. The 3rd and 4th values should render like so:

> [image: Man-kiss-man]

and

> [image: Short-and-white]

Thoughts…

- It turns out that a long-press on the race horse fails to show skin tones on iOS, so let's assume that's just an oversight, perhaps related to the near-impossibility of judging the jockey's skin tone at standard emoji sizes. I still can't figure out the problem with `u = "1f468-2764-1f48b-1f468"`
- Apologies if this question comes out at all unclear. Chrome and Safari have different behaviors w.r.t these combo-emoji, so only the linked images are guaranteed to appear to you the way I see them on my end.
- These emoji are all either skin-tone renderings or tokens of same-sex affection. Is there some sort of bizarre latent racism & homophobia lurking in the system?!  (Cue the conspiracy theories.)
- Note that my attempt to use the zero-width joiner, `u{200d}` didn't help.

So, bug in Apple & Chrome's handling of certain emoji, or is there yet another idiosyncrasy of the standard that I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no conspiracy, the bugs are in your code.

- The first character can be produced with:

  `U+1F468` `U+200D` `U+2764` `U+FE0F` `U+200D` `U+1F48B` `U+200D` `U+1F468`

  Note the ZERO WIDTH JOINER (`U+200D`) between each character, and the VARIATION SELECTOR-16 selector (`U+FE0F`) on the HEAVY BLACK HEART (`U+2764`) to ensure the emoji presentation style is used.

  Refer to [this table](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-zwj-sequences.html) for a complete list of implemented multi-person groupings.
- `U+1F3C7` HORSE RACING is not an emoji modifier base, and so it does not support skin tone modifiers.

Comment: Aha! That explains the difference in the full JSON which has both, e.g., `"unicode":"1f468-2764-1f468"` *and* `"unicode_alternates":"1f468-200d-2764-fe0f-200d-1f468"`. The latter includes the joiner & selector codes!